# concatenate DISTINCT string values in pentaho data integration

Tags: mysql, pentaho, etl

I am new to pentaho data integration. How can i concatenate distinct string values ?

```
bse_id values
100     A1
100     A1
100     A2
150     A1
150     B1
150     C1
150     C1
```

putput should be

```
bse_id values
100    A1,A2
150    A1,B1,C1
```

In Mysql, i can use 
    select bse_id,group_concat(distinct values) from table group by 1;

In SPOON, i have tried group_by step and memory group_by 
both are resulting in duplicate values.
I'm getting output as

```
 bse_id values
    100    A1,A1,A2
    150    A1,B1,C1,C1
```

Please help me in removing the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with a `Group by` step. Be sure the input to the step is sorted on the `bse_id` field, then select `values` as the subject of an aggregate field and set the type to 'Concatenate strings separated by,'. That should give you exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have 2 Group by Steps:

Try the following three steps after input:

1. Step: Sort by BOTH - 'bsi_id' and 'values'
2. Step: Group by BOTH - 'bsi_id' and 'values' (no aggregation here)
3. Step: Group by 'bsi_id'; aggregate 'values' with Type "Concatenate strings separated by ,"

Output is:

```
bse_id; values
100; A1, A2
150; A1, B1, C1
```

This should work fine.
Bye